# Is Umbraco the right solution for me?

Tags: c#, cms

I want to start posting a webcomic, and include a few separate pages about the characters in the comic as well, along with the standard "about" and so on.

Requirements:

- The platform should be free.
- When I post a new comic, it should be pretty easy to add.
- Additional text I add around the comic, or on other pages, should not require me to open up html (or .cshtml) to add.

Is Umbraco the right thing for me to use? I can program in C#, and styling shouldn't be too much of a problem. But is the platform right for this type of content?

Comment: I would recommend looking at Orchard as well http://www.orchardproject.net/

Answer (score -1):

The chief purpose of a CMS is to allow people who don't know how to program to build, or at least maintain, a website. You know how to program, so most of the complexity of a CMS will only weigh you down.

What's more, Umbraco, like most CMSes, creates a dynamic website, whereas it sounds like you only need static pages.

So, a static site generator should cover all your needs. Or just use an HTML templating system (which is typically a component of a static site generator), since your third bullet point and to a lesser extent your second are the only reasons that writing plain old HTML and CSS with a text editor doesn't meet your requirements. For this purpose, reStructuredText and Markdown are likely perfectly serviceable HTML templating systems.

Comment: Why would he need static pages? A CMS would work just as well.

Comment: Forgot to add: The chief purpose is not just for "people who don't know how to code". They are good way of making website management and security a little bit easier. They also allow their users to get things done a little bit faster and sometimes more efficient. Wordpress has a feature to allow you to schedule articles. That way you can put as many articles in as you want, but have a set schedule for them to go out. Sometimes its better to build the car, than to have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Chillie I don't understand your thinking. For example, how could a CMS hosting dynamic pages possibly be more secure than a tree of static pages? And what's the advantage of WordPress's built-in scheduling over a plain old cron job? You can accomplish everything with a CMS that you could with static pages, but if static pages suffice, why pay the costs of complexity?

Comment: You are assuming that he wants to set up a cron job (which is not a thing in the windows environment, by the way) and deal with static pages. Based of his question, he does not. It's like he is asking "is this a good computer to buy" and you are saying "prebuilt computers are to allow users that don't know how to build them to have a computer. You should go build your own computer". This doesn't answer his question.

Comment: @Chillie OP asked "But is the platform right for this type of content?". That's what I answered. Beyond that, you seem coming at this problem with a different set of assumptions from mine (e.g., the phrasing "deal with static pages" suggests there is some sort of difficulty), so I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: Static pages are not a platform. They are static pages. Wordpress, Joomla, Umbraco, Orchard, .NetNuke, PhpNuke, these are all platforms.